# templated singleton class - how to handle private constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, singleton, private

I realize how many times this have been talked about but I have not found an appropriate solution for my problem. I have just implemented a Meyer's singleton class into my project but I would like to make a template out of it so that I can use it as e.g.

`class Game : public Singleton<Game>
{ /* stuff */
}`

And I have my class defined like this

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T& Instance();

private:
    Singleton();
    //declare them to prevent copies
    Singleton(Singleton const&);
    void operator=(Singleton const&);

};// END OF CLASS DEFINITION


// METHODS' DEFINITIONS

template<typename T>
T& Singleton<T>::Instance()
{
    static T _instance;
    return _instance;
}
```

Allowing ctor to be `public` will destroy whole vision of Singletons.

**EDIT**
Ok, so I have updated my `Game` class to befriend `Singleton<Game>`

```
class Game : public Singleton<Game>
{
friend class Singleton<Game>;
//...
}
```

But now I have something like:

> undefined reference to 'Singleton< Game >::Singleton()'

in function `Game::Game()` which is empty

Comment: What exactly is your problem? That Game cannot call the ctor of Singleton<Game> because the Singleton-ctor is private? -> make the ctor of Singleton protected. Or is it that the ctor of Game has to be public so that Singleton::instance can construct the Game-object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Allowing ctor to be public will destroy whole vision of Singletons.

No, not really. `Game` should have a private constructor. Constructor of `Singleton` is irrelevant. An instance of `Singleton<Game>` will not help anyone to get another instance of `Game`, which is what you're interested in.

Anyway, you can declare the constructor `protected`. Alternatively, you can keep the constructor `private` and befriend the template parameter. Except this does not work in C++03. Should work in C++11 though. But there's a little trick:

```
template <typename T>
struct wrapper
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
    friend class wrapper<T>::type;
```

Update: `Game` should befriend `Singleton<Game>`, or at least `Singleton<Game>::Instance`, to allow its constructor to be called.

Comment: Please take a look at my update. I have tried both befriend `Singleton<Game>` and using protected constructors but now I have a compile error.

Comment: This is a linker error. You need to define the constructor, not just declare it. The simplest way is to add the empty body `{}` to the constructor declaration, right inside the class.

Answer (score 2):

ctor Singleton() -> protected?